# Dynamics CRM: making "Regarding" field clickable in Outlook if its name is blank

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, dynamics-crm

In Dynamics CRM, the "Regarding" field is not displayed in Outlook 2010, if primary field is empty. (Primary field is a field whose value is displayed in lookups.)

Say we have a lead where First Name and Last Name are empty. In IE it will display only icon, but it's still clickable.

[image: Lookup with blank name in IE]

In Outlook there's no icon, so it is not clickable.

[image: Lookup with blank name in Outlook]

Is there a way to display icons of "Regarding" entity, or make it clickable in any other than modifying data?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand your question. What is the "Regarding" field?

Comment: Regarding in CRM: http://imgur.com/tJvft
Regarding in Outlook: http://imgur.com/2lY5G

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You have to fill in the primary fields or else outlook doesnt treat this as a hyperlink if the field is empty, hence making it unclickable.